# TypeError: expected string but received array postman

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I was trying to send form data that has multiple fields with the same name, I'm getting back "TypeError: expected string but received array".

I think the problem is with postman, I want to have multiple participant fields, and those would be added to the should be added to the array.

[image]

[final results of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxW2L.png)

```js
// this is from models/Battle

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const BattleSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now
    },
    category: {
        type: Number, 
        required: true // this will come from the selected category 
    },
    winner: {
        type: Number, 
        default: 0
    },
    status: {
        type: Number, 
        default: 0 // 0 means the battle is closed, 1 means the battle is open for votes, the status will stay 0 until all participants dropped
    },
    participants: [
        {
          participant: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
          }
        }
    ]
    
 

});

module.exports = Battle = mongoose.model('battles', BattleSchema);

//this is from routes/api/battles

// @route   POST api/battles
// @desc    Create battle
// @access  Private
router.post(
    '/create-battle',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
      const { errors, isValid } = validateBattleInput(req.body);
  
      // Check Validation
      if (!isValid) {
        // If any errors, send 400 with errors object
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
        console.log(errors);
      }

      const newBattle = new Battle({
         user: req.user.id,
         category: req.body.category,
         participant: req.body.participant
      });      

      //save
      newBattle.save().then(battle => {       

        // const participant = req.body.participant;
        const participant = req.body.participant;


        // add participants to array 
        battle.participants.push( participant );
        console.log(typeof req.body.participant);

        // get the inserted id  
        const battleId = battle._id;
        res.json(battle);      

      
      });
    }
);

// this is battle validation 
const Validator = require('validator');
const isEmpty = require('./is-empty');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function validateBattleInput(data) {
  let errors = {};

  data.category = !isEmpty(data.category) ? data.category : '';
  data.participant = !isEmpty(data.participant) ? data.participant : '';

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.category)) {
    errors.category = 'Category field is required';
  }

  // if (Validator.isEmpty(data.challenger)) {
  //     errors.challenger = 'Challenger field is required';
  // }

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.participant)) {
    errors.participant = 'Participant field is required';
  }

  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors)
  };
};
```

Comment: `TypeError: expected string but received array`  has been throwed by `validator` lib, you can follow the error stacktrace then check again. `validation/battle.js line 18`. I see, `participants` (in model) != `participant` (in creating data)

Answer (score 1):

TypeError: Expected string but received Array. ---throws an error in postman as well as in a terminal window. I suspect it could be the user schema definition mismatch

Please check your user model user schema  eg
name: {
 type: String,
required: true
 }
it's receiving something else than expected.

Answer (score 0):

try in your "body" tab, selecting "raw", and then to the right, select "JSON (application/json)" instead of "text".

I'm assuming your API endpoint uses JSON instead of a url-encoded form data, just because you are running an API using express and mongoose. but you should clarify that on the question if it isn't the case.

Write a proper JSON body, I mean, use double quotes for keys as in:

```
{"model": { "property": "value",  "property2": 1}}
```

and try with the wrapping object `{"model": <YOUR BODY HERE>}` or without to see what works for you, as it's typical to wrap the object, but sometimes people don't use them.  (seeing this in your code: `req.body.participant` makes me think you probably don't).

(PS: not related with the question, but personally prefer ARC or Insomnia for rest clients, as the interface for them is cleaner)

Comment: I don't think I'll have this problem when I get to the UI and can work on the actual forms because I can just pass in property[] in the name property, that doesn't work in this case though.

Comment: is your app a MEAN-like one?

Comment: yea except mern using react instead of angular, I need multiple participants added to the participant array. the model looks like participants: [  { participant: { type: String, required: true }}  ] I tried changing type to array but it doesn't work like that, it actually used to work with type: String

Comment: I think I figured it out, since participant is considered an array I can loop through participant and add to the array, that's what I would do if this was a php app.

Comment: oh BAM the looping through the participant array worked `const participants = req.body.participant;

        participants.map(battlers => {
          battle.participants.unshift({participant: battlers});
        });`

Comment: I updated postman picture with the results that I was hoping to get, everything seems to be working now, I looped over the participant array, I was thinking, what what I do if this was PHP, since that's my specialty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data to be sent in participants array all the fields should be participants and not participant

try sending data through raw data and then selecting application/data for better formatting

Answer (score 0):

When testing in postman - Just figured out Key value must match your validation function defined variables. It's better to be consistent across your development.

Comment: Please don't post two answers for the same thing, try editing your other answer!